# XSLT: using node-set causes problems with selecting nodes on second pass

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to do a multi-pass with an XSLT. So first I declare a variable with the first pass result, and then apply templates for the second pass like in the code below. In this case the second pass does not work as I expect.

As a simple example I want to add a `<NewNode>` tag for every `<Node>` in the first pass. The input XML can be anything in this example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:for-each select="Node">
        <NewNode/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="firstPass">
        <Data>
            <Node/>
            <Node/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="secondPass"
            select="exslt:node-set($firstPass)/*"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In this case the for-each does not work, like there is no such thing as `<Node>` in the xml. Other selects also can't find the respective nodes, the for-each is just an example. I tried using another template that matches "Node" instead of "node()|@", but we never enter it as if the tag is missing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Node" mode="secondPass">
    <NewNode/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node" mode="secondPass"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="firstPass">
        <Data>
            <Node/>
            <Node/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="secondPass"
            select="exslt:node-set($firstPass)/*"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of both codes is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Node />
    <Node />
</Data>
```

When I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <NewNode />
    <NewNode />
    <Node />
    <Node />
</Data>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <NewNode />
    <Node />
    <NewNode />
    <Node />
</Data>
```

As an input you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Body>  
</Body>
```

Comment: "*does not work*" is not a good description of a problem. Please post a **complete** example (one that can be reproduced by copy-and-paste), and show the expected output.

Comment: Why do you have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` in the stylesheet if your wanted results don't use any namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not explained which result you want and which one you get when you say your code does not work but one problem in your approach is that your stylesheet has `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` and that way puts result elements (including those of the first pass) into that namespace, yet your match patterns or path expressions don't take the namespace into account. I don't see any XHTML in your snippets so I wonder why you have used that namespace. If your real element names are those of XHTML elements, meaning you need that namespace, then you need to make sure your templates match on the XHTML namespace with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
            exclude-result-prefixes="exslt xhtml">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:Node" mode="secondPass">
    <NewNode/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="firstPass">
        <Data>
            <Node/>
            <Node/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="secondPass"
            select="exslt:node-set($firstPass)/*"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an alternative, if your temporary elements are not supposed to be XHTML elements and you want to select or match them without using a prefix, then you need to use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Node" mode="secondPass">
    <NewNode/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="secondPass">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="secondPass"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="firstPass" xmlns="">
        <Data>
            <Node/>
            <Node/>
        </Data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="secondPass"
            select="exslt:node-set($firstPass)/*"/>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, if all your elements are not XHTML elements, then I would simply drop the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` from the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, when I removed the namespace it started to work!